# base class constructor parameter in trait

Tags: scala, traits

I have a base class with some constructor parameter:

```
abstract class HugeClass(implicit context: ContextClass) {
   ...
}
```

Because the class gets bigger and bigger and only some subclasses need some special behaviour, I want to refactor it into a trait. However, I still need access to `context` in the trait. I tried this:

```
trait SomeTrait extends HugeClass {
    def myMethod = {
        context.method
    } 
}
```

But the scala compiler says: *not found: value context*. How can I solve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parameter `context` is turned into a private field. The fact that a parameter or a member is implicit does not mean it is public - it is implicit only within the class it is visible in (`HugeClass`).
Turn `context` into a `val`:

```
abstract class HugeClass(implicit val context: ContextClass) {
   ...
}
```

and it will work.